# Querying Repository with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using code first approach with Entity Framework 6. Three of my model classes implements inheritance and each of these model has collection which also implement inheritance. I am using TPH inheritance strategy. Everything works fine and  I can insert/update with no problem at all. However, I get when I try to read data from the repo. The I get is shown below.

I have include my models, entity configuration and the line that throws this exception:

> The include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the select operator for collection navigation properties

Code:

```
public abstract class OrderSup
{
    public OrderSup()
    {
        DetailOrderSups = new HashSet<DetailOrderSup>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    public string CusSupCode { get; set; }
    public decimal NetAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxAmount { get; set; }
    public string DespatchSatus { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DetailOrderSup 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product OrderedProducts { get; set; }
    public InvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderSup OrderSup { get; set; }
}

public class Order : OrderSup
{
    public int SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public InvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : OrderSup
{
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    //public string AlocationStatus { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderDetails : DetailOrderSup
{
    public bool IsOrderPaid { get; set; }
    public decimal Outstanding { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisputed { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetails: DetailOrderSup
{
    public bool IsOrderPaid { get; set; }
    public decimal Outstanding { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> GetPurchaseOrders()
{
    // THIS IS LINE THAT THROWS EXCEPTION
    return this.AppContext.Orders.OfType<PurchaseOrder>()
                          .Include(o => o.DetailOrderSups.OfType<PurchaseOrderDetails>()); 
}

 class OrderSupConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderSup>
    {
        public OrderSupConfiguration()
        {
            HasMany(p => p.DetailOrderSups)
            .WithRequired(o => o.OrderSup)
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderId);    
        }
    }
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: I forgot to add my entity configuration.

Comment: `OfType` isn't supported in `Include`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then, how do I get to include PurchaseOrderDetails?